# How to properly advise macros used by functions if earlier byte-compilation is present?

Tags: byte-compilation, advice

I am trying to customize the looks of org-agenda and, in order to do so, I would like to advice the macro `org-agenda--insert-overriding-header`; this macro appears to be used in several functions.  However, if I add the advice in my init file, it does not appear to work.

I guess that it is because the macro has been earlier expanded during byte-compilation and thus my advice is never actually taken.

This leads to the more general question: is there a way to effectively add an  advice a macro if such macro is used in a function that has been byte-compiled?  Can I force byte-recompilation of some functions only? Do I need to give up byte-compilation altoghether?

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Or maybe you haven't completely specified just what you're really trying to do (and why)? The compiled definition of a function won't have any reference to macros used to expand its source-code definition.

Comment: Yes, so how do I force recompilation of a given function after altering a macro that is called within that function? (assuming that I can even do that?)

Comment: You need to 1. install the advice, 2. eval the original function definition, 3. call byte-compile 'function. But it would be better to 1. install the advice, 2. recompile the source file, so the result gets written to an *.elc. 3. keep the advice always installed. That way, any package updates can compile with this activated advice.